# return all users each user with posts and each post with comments laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel eloquent and I made models (User,Post,Comment)

the relaitions is

**User** model

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

**Post** model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Comment** model

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

I Want to return all users and each user has an object of his posts and each post of those has an object of all comments

I have this query

```
$users = \App\User::with('posts')->\get();
return $users;
```

it returns objects of users and each user have object of his posts, but no comments object

now the problem is

in php, e.g. I can `return user[0]->posts[0]->coments()`
and it return the comments

but I can not see this comments in javascript or mobile phones as API 
it returns *"try to get property of non object"*

so .. **I want to use the comments in js or API**

I can get the comments using for loop but I looking for better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$users = \App\User::with('posts', 'posts.comments')->get();
return $users;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @MoawiaMeghari - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: of course I will, but it tells me to wait 12 minute to accept an answer

Comment: Ya no problem, just informing you!! By the way - Thanks